# HTML5 Video Rendering on ASP.net MVC5 website

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a bit of a problem, I dont know why but I cant render video files on my site.

I made a project where my Videos are inside my asset folder, and it is called by a video tag.
It works on localhost, there are no problems but when I publish it

The images work but the video does not play.

Then I Tried Blob Storage, using Azure Storage Explorer I uploaded my video files in a public Blob. But same thing, it does not load but I can download the video file (I dont get this part)

Lastly I use Media Service which works good but the problem is, the Azure Manager of Media Service sucks, I need to upload tons of video and the UX in Azure does not help at all. there is no batch uploading or what so ever and I need to publish one by one. 
So I made a code for it (Upload -> Encode -> Publish) but my biggest problem now is Upload.

The part where I will upload my IassetFile
                        assetFile.Upload(uploadFilePath);
This always fail with 100mb++ Files, but if it is 20mb++ it works ok.

I'm quite a bind, I dont know anymore what to do.

Can anyone give suggestion on how Can I proceed with this problem, the best case is that 
Is there a configuration in azure website where I can activate so I can play videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert video files you have already uploaded into blob storage into media services assets.  The guidance from Microsoft on how to do this is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj933290.aspx

You should also be able to leverage the raw MP4 blob that is produced as the baseline media asset if you don't wish to utilise smooth streaming or similar services.  This asset has a long URL with a SAS access key.

Comment: I have a bit of the problem with that code, the code is for smooth

Comment: Yes, but in order to create smooth streaming Azure Media Services will  create a baseline MP4 asset which is stored in blob storage.  You can serve this asset directly (it will not use streaming but will play out fine in HTML5 players).

Comment: Ok Now I got it why it is having an error, I'm quite confuse because for Media Service, the thing with not associated I thought it is in Different account but actually it just means it is in another blob storage. So that is why I am having 404 because I am trying to access without "key". 

What I did is made a public folder in my Media Storage and put there the files so I dont need any keys